# Text to speech not working

Tags: iphone, ios, text-to-speech

I am using sfoster iPhone TTS. I want to convert a text into speech & also want to split the string into it's letters & both the text & each of the letter will be pronounced. But its not pronouncing the text & the letters. My code is following:

```
-(void)spellOut:(NSString *)text{

[fliteEngine speakText:text];   
[fliteEngine setPitch:100.0 variance:50.0 speed:2.5];
[fliteEngine setVoice:@"cmu_us_rms"];

/* split a string into an array */

NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[text length]];

for (int i=0; i < [text length]; i++) {
    NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [text characterAtIndex:i]];
    [characters addObject:ichar];
}

/* set letter from each index of the array */

for (int i=0; i<[characters count]; i++) {

    NSString *letter = [characters objectAtIndex:i];

    NSLog(@"%@\n",letter);

    [fliteEngine speakText:letter];
    [fliteEngine setPitch:100.0 variance:50.0 speed:2.5];
    [fliteEngine setVoice:@"cmu_us_rms"];   
  }

}
```

Where is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First it seems you have not initiated FliteTTS so do this first

```
fliteEngine = [[FliteTTS alloc] init];
```

Then as I came to know through your code it works if you use this code
Without pronouncing all characters separately.

```
-(void)spellOut:(NSString *)text{

[fliteEngine speakText:text];
[fliteEngine setPitch:100.0 variance:50.0 speed:2.5];
[fliteEngine setVoice:@"cmu_us_rms"];

/* split a string into an array */

NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[text length]];

for (int i=0; i < [text length]; i++) 
 {
    NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [text characterAtIndex:i]];
    [characters addObject:ichar];
}


}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I have initiated Flite TTs into my viewDidLoad method already. & this portion of code u wrote only works for the full string. but i need to pronounce the letters also. They are not working!

Comment: @Leo this framework does not support to  pronounce the letters you have to use google apis for this I have mentioned the code and that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


 @try {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.wordToSpeech = @"What do functional foods mean? According to the April 2009 position on functional foods by the American Dietetic Association (ADA), all foods are functional at some level, because they provide nutrients that furnish energy, sustain growth, or maintain and repair vital processes. While the functional food category, per se, is not officially recognized by the Food and Drug Administration, the ADA considers functional foods to be whole foods and fortified, enriched, or enhanced foods that have a potentially beneficial effect on health. Thus a list of functional foods might be as varied as nuts, calcium-fortified orange juice, energy bars, bottled teas and gluten-free foods. While many functional foods—from whole grain breads to wild salmon—provide obvious health benefits, other functional foods like acai berry or brain development foods may make overly optimistic promises. Thus, it’s important to evaluate each functional food on the basis of scientific evidence before you buy into their benefits";

    [self sentenceToSpeech];
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"%s\n exception: Name- %@ Reason->%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[exception name],[exception reason]);
}

}

- (void)sentenceToSpeech{

@try {

    NSString *sentenceToSpeech = @"";

    if (0 == self.totalCountPlayed) {

        sentenceToSpeech = [self.wordToSpeech substringToIndex:100];
        self.totalCountPlayed = 100;

    }
    else{

        NSString *tempString = [self.wordToSpeech substringFromIndex:self.totalCountPlayed];

        if (100 <= [tempString length]) {

            sentenceToSpeech = [tempString substringToIndex:100];
            self.totalCountPlayed += 100;
        }
        else
        {
            sentenceToSpeech = tempString;
            self.totalCountPlayed = 0;
        }
    }

    [self speechUsingGoogleTTS:sentenceToSpeech];
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"%s\n exception: Name- %@ Reason->%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[exception name],[exception reason]);
}

}

- (void)speechUsingGoogleTTS:(NSString *)sentenceToSpeeh{

@try {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.mp3"];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=%@",sentenceToSpeeh];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] ;
    [request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                     error:&error];
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];


    NSError        *err;
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                       [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&err];

        [self.player prepareToPlay];
        [self.player setNumberOfLoops:0];
        [self.player setDelegate:self];
        [self.player play];

    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"%s\n exception: Name- %@ Reason->%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[exception name],[exception reason]);
}
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{

@try {

    if (0 != self.totalCountPlayed) {

        [self sentenceToSpeech];
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"%s\n exception: Name- %@ Reason->%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[exception name],[exception reason]);
}
}
```

Use this code this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timer for spellout the text,

in `.h`

```
NSString *speechText;
int tempVariable;
```

in `.m`

```
-(void)spellOut:(NSString *)text{

    speechText=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text];

    tempVariable=0;

    [fliteEngine speakText:text];   
    [fliteEngine setPitch:100.0 variance:50.0 speed:2.5];
    [fliteEngine setVoice:@"cmu_us_rms"];

    NSTimer *popupTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runner addTimer:popupTimer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

-(void)timerAction:(NSTimer *)theTimer {

    if(tempVariable<speechText.length) {

        NSString *letter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[speechText characterAtIndex:tempVariable]];

        NSLog(@"%@\n",letter);

        [fliteEngine speakText:letter];
        [fliteEngine setPitch:100.0 variance:50.0 speed:2.5];
        [fliteEngine setVoice:@"cmu_us_rms"];
        tempVariable++;
    } else {

        [theTimer invalidate];
        theTimer=nil;
    }

}
```

Comment: Should there be speechText instead of lbl.text?

Comment: Well...bro the text is being pronounced but not the letters!

Comment: can't understand whats the problem!

Comment: yeah it should speak so, but it is not working! very strange!